# Gat Array of form inputs Angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular2-forms

I am building an application in Angular2 and am struggling to get the value for the following inputs.

**HTML Form**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createPage(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <textarea name="meta[keywords]" id="keywords" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <textarea name="meta[description]" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
...
export class AppComponent {
   createPage(form: NgForm) {
      console.log(form.value.meta);
   }
}
```

As it stands it keeps returning null. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use template driven forms or model driven forms. If you're looking for a basic template driven approach, this would fix it:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createPage()">
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="meta.keywords" name="meta[keywords]" id="keywords" class="form-control">
    </textarea>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="meta.description" name="meta[description]" id="description" class="form-control">
    </textarea>
</form>

...
export class AppComponent {
   meta: any = {};
   createPage() {
      console.log(this.meta.keywords, this.meta.description);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is `ngModel` to bind the values from your form. So you need to add that:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createPage(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <textarea name="meta[keywords]" ngModel></textarea>
    <textarea name="meta[description]" ngModel></textarea>
</form>
```

BUT, with `name="meta[keywords]"`, keep in mind, this is only a string literal name for as the name of the property in the object created by the form, so your object would look like this:

```
{
  "meta[keywords]": "",
  "meta[description]": ""
}
```

... which means that `console.log(form.value.meta);` will print `undefined`, even `console.log(form.value.meta[keywords])` value will throw an error, because it's trying to read an object property of `meta`. Only way which would work is: `form.value['meta[keywords]']`, which would then point to the actual property of the form object.

So all in all, I guess that what you really want is to use `meta` object for your form. Then use two-way-binding like Bart suggested.